# How to set multi companies to work on the same chart of accounts in Odoo-11?

Tags: odoo-11

Recently i changed from Odoo-10 to Odoo-11 but now i am stuck on this step.
I am unable to setup multi companies that share the same account of charts.
In Odoo-10 we had these options where i can do what i want if i untick the option [this company has its own chart of accounts] (as shown in the image) but i can't find similar options in Odoo-11.

i have tried to find any module to bring back those options but i couldn't find any.

Image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/thExu.jpg

Answer (score 0):

You cant share charts of accounts with different companies because every company will manage its own accounting in odoo.

Comment: Thank you for your response. but sorry i didn't get exactly what you mean.
If you saw the image i posted, in odoo-10 we had that ability to un-select the option [this company has its own chart of account].

I want to know how to achieve the same effect of un-selecting this option but in odoo-11.

Comment: I am still finding from long time but didnot find anything for this.